# How to use Twitter Bootstrap grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap grid system, but I'm having some trouble. Deleting the jQuery script link does get it to throw an error so I assume it is loading the js file, but I'm not getting the divs being displayed as I want them to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php require_once 'controllers/loadController.php'; ?>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Test title</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content--> 
      <?php echo loadController("sidebar"); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
      <?php echo loadController("main"); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

All I get is the output of the loadController. I'm on windows, using Apache (working fine), and when I click the links in "view source" it displays the minified/not minified text - so the files exist. See image below:

[image]

Comment: To be clear, "as I want them to" is "as it is on the bootstrap page" i.e. in a table of sorts but I'm just getting two unstyled divs, one after the other.

Comment: What's the CSS for span2 and span10?

Comment: can you share screenshot of the screen (output)

Comment: @Ankur140290 output: http://imgur.com/XMDG5Ee
@ BSMP Whatever Twitter Bootstrap gives it (it's theirs)

Comment: @asd It seams that your bootstrap.css id not loaded. Please check the same. If you have Chrome, then inspect in the same.

Comment: @Ankur140290 http://imgur.com/ognswP0 It looks like it's been loaded. Those are warnings, there are no errors.

Comment: @asd Their is one error saying "Expected end of value but found '\9 '. I would suggest you to open the page in chrome and check the o/p.

Comment: @Ankur140290 bootstrap.css has not been modified by me, I just downloaded it as is from the bootstrap website. Nonetheless, I changed that line and that warning went away but the page looks the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you meant right you want you sidebar on the left and body content on the right and ou are using span2 and span10 for that which is found on bootstrap 2.x.x  it is 3.3.4 now and can you try the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
      <!--Sidebar content--> 
      Sidebar content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
      <!--Body content-->
     Body content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and live [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fzq4zkez/)

And for more info refer to the [twitter bootstrap 3.x grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) instead of [twitter bootstrap 2.x grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome but I strongly recommend reading the documentation for media queries (what resolution or device will show the columns in what way) etc. at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid